# For loop from python to retrieve data from SQL row by row

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, xampp

i am facing trouble retrieving data row by row from MySQL to Python to do some converting.i have established a connection on the database itself but do not know how to perform a for loop in python to retrieve data so that i can convert them.(informations:XAMPP V3.2.2,MYSQL workbench 5.2.34 CE,python 3.4.4)

Comment: Can we see your code please ?

Comment: If you try Googling "MySQL Python Tutorial" - you might find some useful information like this : http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/

Comment: import mysql.connector
conn=mysql.connector.connect(user='user',password='',host='localhost',database=db')
mycursor=conn.cursor() 
mycursor.execute("SELECT * from db")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
rows = mycursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
 mycursor.execute("UPDATE db.bd SET bdtime=from_unixtime(unix_time);")
 conn.commit()

Comment: Please add the code to your question, and not in a comment, with proper indentation. It is very difficult to read the code from a comment.